# why does git show unicode as binary?

Tags: git, unicode, internationalization

Why does `git status` and related tools treat unicode in filenames as binary?

```
[991]anarcat@marcos:test$ git init foo
Dépôt Git vide initialisé dans /home/anarcat/test/foo/.git/
[992]anarcat@marcos:test$ cd foo
[993]anarcat@marcos:foo$ touch hé
[994]anarcat@marcos:foo$ git add hé
[996]anarcat@marcos:foo$ git status --porcelain
A  "h\303\251"
```

I expected this to be:

```
A hé
```

git deals with accents and unicode fine in the *content* of files, why are filenames special?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default git prints non-ascii file names in quoted octal notation. You can disable this

```
git config --global core.quotepath off
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for, thanks René! :) i wish this was the default... at least git should respect my locale...